# Reading Mails with JavaMail in Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, jakarta-mail, kotlin-coroutines

I am using android javamail library 1.6.2. I am trying to read mails and return it as a list of custom objects in fragment to display them in recycler view. The code I am using for reading mails is:

```
fun readMails(host: String, port: String, 
              username: String, password: String): List<Mail>? {
    var folder: Folder? = null
    var store: Store? = null

    return try {
        val properties = Properties()
        properties[HOST] = host
        properties[PORT] = port
        properties[START_TLS] = "true"
        val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties)

        // Create IMAP store object and connect with the server
        store = session.getStore(PROTOCOL)
        store.connect(host, username, password)

        // Create folder object and open it in read-only mode
        folder = store.getFolder(FOLDER_TYPE)
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)

        // Fetch messages from the folder and print in a loop
        val messages = folder.messages

        val mails = messages.map {
            Mail(
                messageNumber = it.messageNumber,
                subject = it.subject,
                senders = it.from.toList().map { address ->
                    MailAddress(
                        type = address.type,
                    )
                },
                content = parseContent(it.content as Multipart)
            )
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "readMails: $mails")
        mails
    } catch (e: NoSuchProviderException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchProviderException: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        null
    } catch (e: MessagingException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MessagingException: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        null
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        null
    } finally {
        folder?.close(false)
        store?.close()
    }
}
```

In fragment I am trying to read mails using:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    val emails = MailHelper.readMails(
        host = "",
        port = "",
        username = "",
        password = ""
    )
    mailAdapter.submitList(emails)
}
```

The problem is that I can print mails in console but I can only print them using `GlobalScope.launch {}`. If I use that I cannot display then in recyclerview using `submitList()` to the adapter. If I use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {}` I keep getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises from the fact that `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` is bound to `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` which is confined to the application '`Main`' or '`UI`' thread meaning your coroutine starts executing on `UI` thread and you get the error.

To solve this you should pass IO dispatcher to the `launch` function

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val emails = MailHelper.readMails(
        host = "",
        port = "",
        username = "",
        password = ""
    )
    mailAdapter.submitList(emails)
}
```

This will make sure that your coroutine executes on thread pool allocated for IO and not on the main thread.

**Note : Dispatchers.IO can't be used to update UI, only UI thread can do that**